# Regarding a characterization of infinite mean

Tags: real-analysis, probability, proof-verification

I have the following claim:

Let $X_n$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with mean 0.
Show that the following are equivalent:

(a) $E|X_i| < \infty$.

(b) For all $\epsilon > 0$, 
    $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty P( |X_1| > \epsilon n ) = \infty. $$

But, in so doing:

Suppose (b) is true.
Then, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(|X_1| > n) = \infty$. 
Thus,
$$E|X_1| =  \int_0^\infty P(|X_1| > x) dx \ge \sum_{n=1}^\infty P(|X_1| > n) = \infty.$$

I am not sure if I am mistaken or the statements are incorrect.
Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

I am leaning more and more towards:

$E|X_i| < \infty$ if and only if 
for all $\epsilon > 0$, 
    $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty P( |X_1| > \epsilon n ) < \infty. $$

Can someone verify if the two are consistent?

Comment: Are you sure you wrote the question correctly?  Do $X_i$ have mean $0$ or is $E[X_i]<\infty$? For part b), is the sum supposed to be $P(|X_\color{red}{1}|>\epsilon n)$?

Comment: Yes. I believe the question is correct as is. We assume $X_i$ iid with mean zero. And the statement (a) states $E[ |X_i| ] < \infty$.

Comment: @HenriL Regarding your edit: You are right about that. To prove it use the inequality $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1_{\{Y \geq n\}} \leq Y \leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 1_{\{Y \geq n\}}$$ which holds for any non-negative random variable $Y$.